# Extract comments

Tags: ruby, parsing, metaprogramming

I have this code in a controller:

```
# =begin action
# url: /albums
# method: GET
# autentication: true
# return: [json, xml]
# =end
def show
    ...
end
```

Is there some gem that reads comments and returns info in json format, or does something like this? I want to get it to manipulate and generate files with this information.

```
{
    "url" => /albums
    "method" => GET
    "autentication" => true 
    "return" => [json, xml]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a gem doing exactly what you want, but the task seems to be pretty easy to devide:
first, you need to parse the file and pull that comments - it shouldn't be difficult to do it with a simple ruby script.
Then having info in format like:

```
url: /albums
method: GET
autentication: true
return: [json, xml]
```

which seems pretty like a YAML, you can do simply

```
YAML::load(string).to_json
```

Comment: Thank, I had thought about doing what you say but I was wondering if there was a gem to do that automatically. I've been lookin Yardoc but it generate html doc directly.